# QGIS Project: where to put CORE_Export definition in Visual studio 2010

Tags: qgis, visual-studio, qt

I am trying to develop a QGIS application with the following setup:
OSGE4W qgis Libs
QT 4.8.5
Windows 7
Visual Studio 2010

I have all the references setup in VS, but am not sure where define the following lines:

```
CORE_EXPORT     __declspec(dllimport);
GUI_EXPORT      __declspec(dllimport);
```

I cannot compile my code unless these are defined.

I do not want to use QTCreator as I don't like the IDE.

Comment: Found it. Just needed to add the defines to the main .h of my project.